# REGEXP_COUNT function not working in redshift

Tags: sql, regex, amazon-redshift

I am running the below code in Redshift

```
select regexp_count('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', '[a-z]{3}');
```

It return the below error message

> ERROR: function regexp_count(unknown, unknown) does not exist
>
> Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You
>   might need to add explicit type casts.
>
> Position: 8

```
select regexp_count('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', '[a-z]{3}');
```

Comment: What does `select version();` show you?

Comment: That command works for me just fine in redshift - its redshift not postgres @a_horse_with_no_name - do you think the redshift version comes into play here? or perhaps they are not using redshift?

Comment: That SQL works fine for me as well

Comment: That SQL is literally the example code given in the Redshift documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/REGEXP_COUNT.html) so if that doesn't work for you then either you're not actually connecting to Redshift or possibly there is something wrong with your Redshift cluster and in that case I'd suggest contacting AWS support.